# Corrupt MySQL log file - cannot start the database

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

My VM ran out of disk space and MySQL wasn't able to write to the log file causing it to crash. Here is the log file:

> 2017-09-05T11:47:00.636352Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
>
> 2017-09-05T11:47:00.650903Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
>
> 2017-09-05T11:47:00.654252Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
>
> 2017-09-05T11:47:00.667475Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
>
> 2017-09-05T11:47:00.669522Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Ignoring the redo log due to missing MLOG_CHECKPOINT between the checkpoint 72827846847 and the end 72827846656.
>
> 2017-09-05T11:47:00.669553Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
>
> 2017-09-05T11:47:01.270002Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
>
> 2017-09-05T11:47:01.270053Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
>
> 2017-09-05T11:47:01.270064Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize plugins.
>
> 2017-09-05T11:47:01.270071Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

I've tried to remove the `ib_log*` file in `/var/lib/mysql` and set `innodb_force_recovery = 3` in `my.cnf` file. But received the same error. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you try `innodb_force_recovery` values 4, 5, 6?

Answer (score 1):

Was able to do a mysqldump, remove everything. Do a clean reinstall of mysql and import it back. Thanks for the help !